# What is spring data jpa and which orm framework does it use?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a project which does not use Hibernate but I have a doubt. Which orm framework it uses please tell me thanks in advance.

Comment: it supports hibernate and eclipselink for sure. others i am not sure

Answer (score 1):

JPA is a Specification, not implementation. So JPA only does not work.
Maybe your project is using spring-data-jpa. spring-data-jpa depends on hibernate.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/2.2.0.RELEASE
<- You can see which libraries are related to spring-data-jpa. hibernate-core is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

JPA is a specification, there are several implementations (Hibernate, EclipseLink, ...).

Spring Data JPA is a framework which is able to use one implementation or an other.

If your project is not using hibernate, it's probably using EclipseLink, you can find this in your pom.xml. If you see Hibernate exclusion :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

and EclipseLink dependency :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.x.x</version>
</dependency>
```

It confirms you are using EclipseLink.

source : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-eclipselink

Comment: i have a doubt here. i have a mapping one to one and one to many so who does this spring data jpa or hibernate orm ? example code here : @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Post post;

Comment: mapping is done by who spring data jpa or hibernate ?

Comment: The mapping is done by the JPA implementation, i.e. Hibernate or EclipseLink

Comment: The mapping is done by you, or the project developper. The annotation you use to do this mapping come from a package you can check in the "import" sections. These are mostly standard JPA annotations, but you can mix in some specific hibernate or eclipselink annotations to get some features.

Comment: who has ORM spring data JPA  or spring data JPA gives only annotation i.e: @Entity?

Comment: and who gives ORM for spring data JPA ?   hibernate or eclipse link ? spring does not have ORM ?

Comment: I've already answered, but I think you are missing the basics of java, maven, Spring, ... to understand the answer.